# PowerShell Library to hide Excel column?

Tags: excel, powershell

Hello i need to hide some columns [without hardcoding in this command](http://kiran-reddy.in/projects/powershell-excel/):

```
Get-SLDocument "C:\123\123.xlsx" | Hide-SLColumn `
-StartColumnName D -ENDColumnName F  -Verbose | Save-SLDocument
```

I tried to create a loop but can't get it to work:

```
$Path = "C:\123\"
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xlsx
Foreach ($wb in $excelFiles) {
Get-SLDocument $wb | Hide-SLColumn  -StartColumnName D `
  -ENDColumnName F  -Verbose | Save-SLDocument
}
```

Comment: Did you come across any hresults or error codes while trying this?

Comment: No. I don't know why... It paste the hole script.

Comment: Did you check whether $wb variable got populated.... try to echo the document name inside the loop.

Comment: why what happened?

Comment: I insert it in loop but the output is the code itself. And more, when i write a crap code in the loop i dont have any error

Comment: check the length of the variable $excelFiles, by echoing the $excelfiles.length

Comment: $excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\fso" -include *.xlsx
(enter)
$excelfiles.length
(enter)
0

Comment: so your excelfiles variable is not getting populated and thus the loop does nothing since it is a null valued expression

Comment: try using get-childitem -path $Path -filter *.xlsx

Comment: $Path = "C:\fso"
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -filter *.xlsx
Foreach ($wb in $excelFiles) {
Get-SLDocument $wb | Hide-SLColumn  -StartColumnName A -ENDColumnName B  -Verbose | Save-SLDocument
} (enter) The output: WARNING: Get-SLDocument : Could Not Find a Workbook at the path specified '123.xlsx'

Comment: Instead of using Spreadsheetlight you are better off using a com-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$path1="C:\fso"
$excelfiles=Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -filter *.xls
$xl=new-object -comobject Excel.application
if($excelfiles.item.membertype -eq "ParameterizedProperty"){
for ($i=0;$i-lt $excelfiles.length;$i++)
{
echo $excelfiles[$i].FullName
$wb=$xl.Workbooks.open($excelfiles[$i].FullName) 
$wb.CheckCompatibility = $False
$wb.sheets(1).columns("U:AF").entirecolumn.hidden=$true
$wb.save()
$wb.close()
}}
else
{
$wb=$xl.Workbooks.open($excelfiles.FullName) 
$wb.CheckCompatibility = $False
$wb.sheets(1).columns("U:AF").entirecolumn.hidden=$true
$wb.save()
$wb.close()

}
$xl.Quit()
```

This uses the com-object to create an excel object and open in excel to hide the columns and close and exit. If you dont want to see the excel object opening and closing you can use $xl.visible=$false after creating the object

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Excuse me one more little question :). When the script is running i have a popup and need to press "Continue" on every file to save it: Microsoft Excell - Compatibility Checker. Any chance to hide this window?

Comment: instead of using the workbooks.open method you can use protectedviewwindow.open method with enableediting=True

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake protectedviewwindows does not have a enablediting property. You can use something like `$wb=$xl.protectedviewwindows.open($excelfiles[$i],Repairmode=True)`

Comment: Ok, I got error again in the ISE unexpected token Repairmode‌​=True in expression or statement

Comment: then just use Protectedviewwindows.open($excelfiles[$i])

Comment: Ok. Now is this error: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method nam
ed 'sheets'.
At D:\Users\h.yordanov\Desktop\Hidecolumns_ver2_for_xls.ps1:13 char:1
+ $wb.sheets(1).columns("U:AF").entirecolumn.hidden=$true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (sheets:String) [], RuntimeExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Ok. I test it and getting this error: At D:\Users\h.yordanov\Desktop\Hidecolumns_ver2_for_xls.ps1:9 char:40
+    $wb=activeprotectedviewwindow.edit(,false)
+                                        ~
Missing expression after unary operator ','.
At D:\Users\h.yordanov\Desktop\Hidecolumns_ver2_for_xls.ps1:9 char:40
+    $wb=activeprotectedviewwindow.edit(,false)

Comment: Ok i understand what to do. Thanks for the time spend for helping me! I have edited the answer too :)

Comment: Uh little embarrassing i discover something. When i have only 1 file in the folder the powershell giving me ~20k+ rows of errors. If the files are more than one there is no problem. Can we fix it?

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say. Can you add the error message?

Comment: Ok. '' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the
 file location is correct.
If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, 
make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.
At D:\Users\h.yordanov\Desktop\Hidecolumns_ver2_for_xls.ps1:8 char:1
+ $wb=$xl.Workbooks.open($excelfiles[$i].FullName)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Is the path you specified exist? does it have any xls files inside it.

Comment: Yes it exist. When there is one file in folder i get the errors but if they are more than one, no problem. No other files exept .xls

Comment: if there's only one file its not a object collection any more its an object thats why its giving the error.....there will be no $excelfiles[$i] there will be only $excelfiles

Comment: ooh... ok :) Thanks

Comment: I have added a if else statement to my answer which checks the membertype then executes different blocks of code based on member type. You might want to add some other error catching blocks such as getting a null valued expression.

Comment: Man you are awesome! I have little edit on the previews and i will add it to the answer... just great!!! :):):)